# Access 2007: Issues with 2 computers exporting same Report as a Text file

Tags: ms-access, text, ms-access-2007

So I have a shared Access 2007 database that essentially creates this large report, full of nasty subreports and all kinds of other no-no's, and then exports it to a text file which we use for input into a different application.  It is a pretty straightforward export of the report to text done using the Access function.  No VBA.

Now on my PC, this text file gets exported exactly as it should, while on a co-workers PC, using the same copy of the Access database, the same report, even using it while remote desktop-ing into the same different computer, has different format, spacing, and other goofy Access Report-to-text issues.

My question is:  What on earth is causing this given the database is exactly the same and we're getting two different results on two computers?  I've tried making sure the default printers are the same, changing around the font in the reports, running it from a Windows server where my co-worker logs into, yet no matter what it seems he always gets the same formatting issues.  It seems somewhere, embedded on his and my machine, we have two different controls that are allowing Access to format and export the Report to text different, even though we are using the same database.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Access has a lot of "exciting" options wrt. default printers, make sure you've checked them all.

Open the report in design mode, then go to page setup and see if a specific printer has been selected for that report (Page Setup|Page).  If it has, try changing it to use the default printer.  If it hasn't, try setting one that you know is on both machines.  Either way, save the report.

Make sure you have http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950488 installed, or the specific printer setting won't stick on saving the report in 2007.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Unfortunately I've tinkered with about every printer setting I can imagine, on my own "working" computer included (which also changes nothing).  I'm stumped.